# Combine LiDAR data with OpenStreetMap

Tags: postgis, postgresql, openstreetmap, lidar, point-cloud

I have already built Ubuntu for OpenStreetMap and I have some LiDAR data file in LAS/LAZ format. Is it possible to make LiDAR data appear in 2D and be a part of OpenStreetMap? If it is, how?
I have already pushed LiDAR to PostgreSQL pointcloud. Make surface model by lopocs and Cesium

And I try some tools to handle LiDAR like liblas, lastool, lidar2tiles,...

Comment: What GIS software are you using? Although LiDAR data can be loaded it's particularly dense, when displayed it ends up looking like a mess in 2d, for that reason consider using LASTools to generate a raster of your LiDAR or at the very least filter your points, ground only, first return, vegetation classes only etc..

Comment: Im using The Rails Port (https://github.com/openstreetmap/openstreetmap-website). I want the lidar is overlay on my osm. Make like a background or something like that. But i not figure how to put it together. Do u have any example or some document for that. Tks!!!

Comment: No sorry, I don't do web applications. I would suggest that you use a product like QGIS to visualize your data before trying to link/upload your LAS files. Consider what your map is intended to portray and modify the settings or convert to a raster on a local PC then when you have a desktop result that you're happy with try to implement the same in OpenStreetMap.

Comment: What exactly do you want as end result? Please be very specific.

Comment: @bugmenot123 I want to make lidar turn to a layer(kind like that) of OSM so when I turn on OSM that lidar will be overlay it. Is that good to understand?

Comment: As 2D display? A dot per lidar point? Colored? Just display or queryable?

Comment: @bugmenot123 I filter that lidar just to take ground point only. And yes i want it as 2D display and if it display a dot like u say then its okay with me. I just dont know how to change it to 2D display and how to overlay it on my OSM. Do u have any suggest about this.

Comment: Matplotlib library of Python can help you to visualize LiDAR data in 2D. The Scatter plot will take the input of X and Y coordinates to display it in 2D, and then you can choose any third variable (like intensity or Z) to colorize the points. I'm not sure about the format required for OSM, but I think either the shapefile format or GeoJSON will work. For this, you can use the Geopandas package of python that will easily convert the LiDAR data to the desired format. Geopandas can also visualize the data in 2D once your point cloud LAS file is converted to shapefile or geopandas dataframe.